# rxjs/Observable and SharePoint REST from a list

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, angular2-services

With Angular 2 I am using

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

to query SharePoint.
The results JSON is something like

```
{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://3 etc...
```

With angular 1 I used `data.d.results` to get the array of useful data
but with the Observable

```
Observable<IKeyDocument[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._KeyDocumentUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IKeyDocument[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

I do see the results in the console but the map does nothing.
Any idea how to get the basic Id and title from all the items in the list?

Comment: With the help of Deborah Kurata I figure out how to do it on a Setter.  which added a function

Comment: onDocsRetrieved(Documents: IDocument[]) {
        this.Documents = Documents['d']; <-- This will bring just the Array of SharePoint Items.  Great bu now I want to get the field "media_src" within each Item in an object named "__metadata":  but I don't see a way to traverse the array and change the mapped interface item. Any one has an idea?